# How do I check if the type of an object assigned to a variable is correct?

Tags: typescript

```
interface FooBar {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: number;
}

const a = { foo: "foo" };
const b = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" };

const c: FooBar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
const d: FooBar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
```

In the code above, I expect it to fail at the last line because the value assigned to d does not satisfy the type of FooBar. If there is no way to know it during the assignment process, I need a way to check it after that. Should I write the code myself to check every key and type of values?

Comment: I believe [type guards](https://rangle.io/blog/how-to-use-typescript-type-guards/) are a common solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is for static type checking only. This means that it will only throw errors at build time (or in your code editor if it's integrated).

```
const d: FooBar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
```

The problem with the line above is that `JSON.parse` returns the type `any`. This is why this line doesn't error even though you've added `const d: FooBar` - `any` matches `FooBar`.

What you can do is

```
const d: FooBar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b)) as {foo: string, bar: string};
```

to let TypeScript know that this stringified then parsed object is actually foo as string and bar as string.

And actually, even better - you can refer to the type of b instead of defining it again

```
const d: FooBar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b) as typeof b;
```

Basically, TypeScript is not that smart as you want it to be here and it's kinda understandable why.

[TypeScript playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0CE5WQbwChlkZMB+ALmQGcwpQBzAbmOQCNcrkQBXAW3bRWAX0KEE6EHWRxkAXgKlM1AERl0q5CNaTpYDgqUa1G1QBoOuNZyhad4vTITUM2XEYBSAZQDyAOQA6AAdcGggACh8AwLoGEEZgGABPCLgASnTdKRkAE1dMHDxFaKDQqHCovyC4piTU9kzZGmQwZOCIdBgOViA)

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address the question: "If there is no way to know it during the assignment process, I need a way to check it after that. Should I write the code myself to check every key and type of values?"  To which the answer is probably "yes, or get some library to do it"